# I want to access data in a JSON object, getting a Typeerror

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

```
caption_text=u'{"confidence_score": 0.847656, "sentence_type": "Abusive"}'

for i in caption_text:
    if i['sentence_type']=='Abusive':
        print i['confidence_score']
```

getting

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not decoded the JSON data, so you are looping over a string.

Decode the data using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and *don't loop*; there is just one dictionary, not a list:

```
import json

caption_text=u'{"confidence_score": 0.847656, "sentence_type": "Abusive"}'
data = json.loads(caption_text)
if data['sentence_type'] == 'Abusive':
    print data['confidence_score']
```

Comment: I am using data=json.loads(caption_text) getting this: error 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read' @Martijn Pieters♦

Comment: @ArpitKamal: check your spelling. You probably wrote `json.load()`, no `s` at the end. It's `json.loads()` with the `s`; the other function reads the data from a file.